# Search .mp3 on computer using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, windows, mp3

I'm trying to search for all the files with an extension **.mp3** in a computer using python 3.x.x i.e. searching through all drives, folders, and subfolders to make a list with all the file name in that list with their path.

```
music_list = ['c:\Users\username\Downlodes\music1.mp3',
              'c:\Users\username\Downlodes\music2.mp3',
              'c:\Users\username\Downlodes\music3.mp3',
              'd:\Folder1\username\oldDownlodes\music4.mp3'
              'e:\music folder\music5.mp3']
```

Please can anyone give me some code to do this function.
I'm using **Windows 8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to check all the subfolders on a directory:

```
subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(folder) if f.is_dir() ]
```

Then you can use this function to retrieve all the files with mp3 extension.

```
import os, fnmatch
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result

find('*.txt', '/path/to/dir')
```

Comment: Will this be able to search through all the drives like `c:` drive `d:` drive `e:` drive and also all the external drives attached to the computer.

Comment: Thank you for the code, I have some doubts in the above program `find('*.mp3', 'E:\\')` running and printing this gives me all the `.mp3` files but takes some time, `subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(folder) if f.is_dir()]` running and printing this gives me all the subfolders, If I pass all the subfolders to the `find` function, will it be faster and efficient. Hope you got my doubts.